# Not a single function error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00937

SQL query:

```
      SELECT SUM (gross_amount) /
           (SELECT TO_CHAR (
                  LAST_DAY (TO_DATE (MAX (accounting_period), 'YYYYMM')),
                 'DD') 
           FROM t_beta_invoice)
       FROM t_beta_invoice_details
```

I tried to calculate the daily invoice amount by dividing the total amount to the number of the days of given month in table t_beta_invoice. Firstly, i get the accounting period, which is in format of 'YYYYMM' and find the last day of it to calculate whether it contains 28,29,30 or 31 days.

But whenever i tried to run this , it gives me `*ORA-00937: not a single-group group function*`. Can anyone help about this situation?

Comment: Is there referential integrity (primary/foreign key )between `t_beta_invoice` and `t_beta_invoice_details` tables?

Comment: Well you appear to be using a character string as the denominator -- might like to change that just for the sake of good form.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this and make sure the second query doesn't return 0.

```
select

(SELECT SUM (gross_amount)      
           FROM t_beta_invoice_details)
 /

 (SELECT TO_CHAR (LAST_DAY (TO_DATE (MAX (accounting_period), 'YYYYMM')), 'DD') 
           FROM t_beta_invoice)
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: thanks for every comment, this one is the most effective one.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, the issue here is that you have a group function *and* a non-group function (the subquery) in the SELECT list.

You *can* use group functions without a group by:
e.g. 
`select count(*), sum(object_id) from all_objects`
works fine but as soon as you include a non-group function, you need to have it in a group by:

No good:
    select object_type, count(*), sum(object_id) from all_objects

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

Works fine:

```
select object_type, count(*), sum(object_id) group by object_type
```

So in your query the subquery is the problem. The catch is that you can't have GROUP BY (subquery) as you'll get `ORA-22818: subquery expressions not allowed here.`

but (at least in 11g) here's an interesting twist: if you add GROUP BY (some constant) you can get it to work:

```
e.g. select (select dummy from dual) as test, sum(1) from dual

ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
```

but

```
select (select dummy from dual) as test, sum(1) from dual group by 'huh?'
```

works.

Otherwise you have to separate the SUM query from the "accounting period" subquery as was suggested by valex.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an [ORA-00937](http://ora-937.ora-code.com/) because "A `SELECT` list cannot include both a group function, such as `AVG`, `COUNT`, `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `STDDEV`, or `VARIANCE`, and an individual column expression, unless the individual column expression is included in a `GROUP BY` clause."

One possible (ugly) solution would be delegating the `SUM` to a subquery.

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(gross_amount) FROM t_beta_invoice_details) /
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(MAX(accounting_period),'YYYYMM')),'DD') 
     FROM t_beta_invoice)
FROM DUAL;
```

Perhaps more elegant (but not much) would be using a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT SUM (t.gross_amount) / x.days
FROM t_beta_invoice_details t,
(SELECT TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(TO_DATE(MAX(accounting_period),'YYYYMM')),'DD') as days
 FROM t_beta_invoice) x
GROUP BY x.days;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

*'ORA-00937: not a single-group group function'*

This error comes if Aggregate function like MAX,MIN,SUM etc is used without using GROUP BY clause.

Comment: No, it comes about if a non-aggregate expression is used in a SELECT (or ORDER BY I suppose) clause along with an aggregate function.